# can't push git readynas

Tags: git, version-control, xcode4

I am writing an app using xcode 4. I have no experience with git, or any form of source control other than copy/paste a new folder!

I have setup git on my readyNAS duo using this [Guide](http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2011/06/09/setting-up-a-remote-git-repository-on-your-readynas.aspx)

I can then add the repository in xcode using:

```
ssh://root@192.168.1.10/opt/git/Developer
```

Developer being the repository.

Xcode then gives me the option to clone, which it can do and it creates an empty repository in the filesystem on the client(MacBook Pro)(I expect it to be empty as I haven't pushed anything to it)!

Any program started and saved in the developer folder can commit locally, however when I wish to push over the network I get this error:

> fatal: 'Developer' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

As a newbie I really don't have any idea about the source of the problem, I have tried this from two client Mac's running snow leopard to my ReadyNAS Duo running 4.1.7.

What do I need to do to address this problem?

Comment: Did you create a local repository for your project? Git may be whining that the local tree is not a git repository. ps. If you can, avoid using root ... more on this topic can be found here and in git documentation.

Comment: yes xcode makes a local git repository for you, I have found a solution to this issue by using visualvsn on windows server instead. svn suits me fine as I'm the only developer

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this from Terminal:

Go to the repository location ( wherever XCode cloned your repo)

Run

```
git remote add Developer ssh://root@192.168.1.10/opt/git/Developer
```

Now try doing the push. I am not familiar with how XCode's git integration works, but the error suggests that it is trying to use a remote named Developer, which is not found.

Usually, it should try doing it on origin, which is the remote that is automatically setup when you clone. See if you can change the remote that it is trying to pust to.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I unfortunately cannot try this as I now can't even clone the repository(booted up today and its stopped working). Will have to solve this issue first!